# How can I randomize csrf token for django admin

Tags: python, django, csrf, penetration-testing, breach-attack

I've just got vulnerability report that came from pentesters for my Django project. The report says my Django app is vulnerable to the **BREACH ATTACK.** SSL is active, cookies are flagged as secure, session cookies are set as secure. HTTP Compressions closed by the sysadmin it is controlled from the Nginx that I have no access. So gzip is closed. Now I want to randomize csrf token for per client-side request for the django admin, especially for the login page. Is there a way to do this in settings.py in a simple way or do I have to write custom admin view? What is the best practice for this issue?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? Django is not susceptible to BREACH since 1.6, see the explanation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#how-it-works).

Comment: I am using django 1.11.6. I don't have any configuration for gzip either...

Comment: @dirkgroten I don't think the breach fixes for CSRF tokens were added until Django 1.10. See [ticket 20869](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/20869)

Comment: Just to check: when you say HTTP compression is closed, do you mean that it is disabled? Also, make sure that you haven't enabled Django's GZip middleware in your settings.

Comment: Indeed, my bad. Django 1.10 it is.

Comment: @Alasdair yes it is disabled at the nginx level. I haven't enabled gzip in my settings.

Comment: If gzip is not enabled by Django or NGINX, and Django 1.11 is automatically changing `{% csrf_token %}` for every request, then I'm not aware of any further changes you have to make. I would ask your pentesters why they thing your app is vulnerable, and what changes they think you should make.